# Can't setup Laravel on Windows via Docker

Tags: laravel, windows, docker

Following:
https://bootcamp.laravel.com/blade/installation

I got an error on this command:
php artisan breeze:install blade

Error Message:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\p7\chirper\node_modules\esbuild
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node install.js
npm ERR! '\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\p7\chirper\node_modules\esbuild'
npm ERR! CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
npm ERR! UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
npm ERR! node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
npm ERR!   throw err;
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Windows\install.js'
npm ERR!     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
npm ERR!     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
npm ERR!     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
npm ERR!     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
npm ERR!   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
npm ERR!   requireStack: []
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Node.js v18.12.1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Megaport\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-27T21_52_29_015Z-debug-0.log

   INFO  Breeze scaffolding installed successfully.
```

How can i fix it ?

Trying to setup Laravel on Windows via Docker.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer...
Had to use sail on all the docker commands.